# How can I extract a column and create a vector out of them?

Tags: python, matrix, vector

```
mat = [['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'], 
       ['6', '7', '8', '9', '10'], 
       ['11', '12', '13', '14', '15']]
```

Suppose, I have this vector of vectors.

Say, I need to extract 2nd column of each row, convert them into binary, and then create a vector of them.

Is it possible to do it without using *NumPy*?

Answer (score 1):

Use zip for transpose list and make loop with enumerate and filter by id with bin().

```
mat = [['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'],
       ['6', '7', '8', '9', '10'],
       ['11', '12', '13', '14', '15']]

vec = [[bin(int(r)) for r in row] for idx, row in enumerate(zip(*mat)) if idx == 1][0]
print(vec) # ['0b10', '0b111', '0b1100']
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. This is achievable with the following code :

```
mat = [['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'], 
       ['6', '7', '8', '9', '10'], 
       ['11', '12', '13', '14', '15']]

def decimalToBinary(n):
    return bin(n).replace("0b", "")
new_vect = []
for m in mat:
    m = int(m[1])
    new_vect.append(decimalToBinary(m))
print (new_vect)
```

Hope this is expected

```
['10', '111', '1100']
```