# How can I extract a column and create a vector out of them using NumPy?

Tags: python, numpy

```
mat = [[ 1.  2.  3.  4.  5.]
       [ 6.  7.  8.  9. 10.]
       [11. 12. 13. 14. 15.]]
```

Suppose, I have this *NumPy* array.

Say, I need to extract the 2nd column of each row, convert them into **binary**, and then create a vector out of them.

How can I do it using *NumPy*?

For instance, if I select 2nd column of this NumPy array, my output should look as follows:

```
[[0  0  1  0],
 [0  1  1  1],
 [1  1  0  0]]
```

I tried as follows:

```
   my_data = np.genfromtxt('data_input')
    print(my_data)
    my_data_2nd_column = my_data[:, 1]
    my_data_2nd_column_binary = Utils.encode(my_data_2nd_column)
    my_2nd_column_binary = np.apply_along_axis(Utils.encode, 1, my_data)
    print(my_2nd_column_binary)
```

Comment: What, **exactly** do you have with `numpy`? The above is a Python `list` object. What do you mean by "convert to binary", what **exactly** is the output you want? Have you tried *anything at all*?

Comment: Please, again, *provide a [mcve]*. It is just basic politeness, and helps you get better answers to your question

Comment: In any case, what is the nature of `mat`? Will it always fit into 4 logical bits?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, 2nd: Yes.

Comment: But why are you posting the same question as before? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68092233/how-can-i-extract-a-column-and-create-a-vector-out-of-them

Comment: @j1, that was without NumPy.

Comment: @user366312 Aha!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numpy has a built-in function for this. First, you can get a particular column using indexing:

```
>>> arr
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
       [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]])
>>> arr[:, [1]]
array([[ 2],
       [ 7],
       [12]])
```

Then, you could use the built-in function, but make sure you convert to unsigned, 8-bit integers:

```
>>> np.unpackbits(arr[:, [1]].astype(np.uint8), axis=1)
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8)
```

Of course, if you need the second dimension to be rank 4, just use slicing again, although, it is probably worth copying if you are going to do lots of operations on the resulting array:

```
>>> np.unpackbits(arr[:, [1]].astype(np.uint8), axis=1)[:, -4:]
array([[0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had done this example, but without using the numpy library.
I commented on all functions.

```
mat = [[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  1,],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 40,],
       [11, 12, 13, 14, 15,]]

# convert the binary into a vector of elements
def split(word):
    return [int(char) for char in word]

# returns the vector size of the largest binary
def binaryBig(lista):
    maior = max(lista, key=int)
    temp = "{0:b}".format(maior)
    return len(split(temp))

# convert the element to binary
def binary(x,big):
    temp = split(format(x, "b"))
    for n in range(len(temp),big):
        temp.insert(0,0)
    return temp

# create the matrix with the binaries
def createBinaryMat(lista):
    big = binaryBig(lista)
    mat = []
    for i in lista:
        mat.append(binary(i,big))
    return mat

# select the column and return the created matrix
def binaryElementsOfColum(colum,mat):
    lista = []
    for i in mat:
        lista.append(i[colum])
    return createBinaryMat(lista)


for i in binaryElementsOfColum(4,mat):
    print(i)
```

Output:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
[1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```